# WordPress: I got rid of the second "home" page, but it's not good enough

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site (2.6.2) in which I have set the Home page to a static page instead of the normal posts page. The ID of this page is 2, so in the WordPress template I have changed the `wp_list_pages` to look like this:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('exclude=2&title_li=&depth=1' ); ?>
```

this works fine, but now the Home page doesn't get "lit up" when it's selected (because in fact it's page_id 2 that is selected, and it doesn't show in the menu). Is there any easy way around this?

If not, in broad outlines, what's the hard way around this? Make my own version of the `wp_list_pages` function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a static page as the front page doens't highlight the menu link, which is at the heart of the question.

So, you could server-side customize (hack) the wp_list_pages function, but here's a client-side option if you so choose:

Use the jQuery library (conveniently it comes with WP 2.2+), call:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

or load your own version:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', '/path/to/your/jquery.js', false, '1.2.1');
```

---

Now add a bit of javascript in your template, something like:

```
if(window.location.href == 'http://www.example.com/'){ //checks for root path - "home" ('http://www.example.com/?p=7' or 'http://www.example.com/2008-10/7' will not match)
    jQuery('#nav > ul > li > a:first').addClass('current_page_item');
}
```

The *a:first* portion assumes the first link in your menu is the home/frontpage link. If it's not, select via href value or position. Here's by postion:

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
jQuery(jQuery('#nav > ul > li > a')[3]).addClass('current_page_item'); //add 'current_page_item' css class so menu item highlighting occurs
```

Example:

> <div id="nav" >
>
> <ul  >
>    <li > <a >Link 0 </a > </li >
>    <li > <a >Link 1 </a > </li >
>    <li > <a >Link 2 </a > </li >
>   **<li > <a >Link 3 </a > </li >**
>    <li > <a >Link 4 </a > </li >
>    <li > <a >Link 5 </a > </li >
>    </ul >
>
> </div >

---

Caveats:

1. Check for the actual name of your menu div id (*#nav* shown here)
2. A nested ul/li menu structure (so more than one level) will require additional code to properly selection the correct *a* element.
3. If menu links are going to change, don't use a positional selection technique, use another hook, like the href value of the link to the home/front page.
4. The *if(window.location.href == 'http://www.example.com/')* portion may need to be a regex if more variation is involved (https, multiple subdomains, etc).

Comment: Thanks for that great answer. Looking at it even briefly, though, I think that hacking a new wp_list_pages function might be a bit less hacky, all told. If I do that, I'll post my code too. Or perhaps I'll take advantage of your answer to get into JQuery :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks Micah. I finally got to it: just commented out the header line in the template, switched the home page in Wordpress and we're good!

Answer (score 2):

You can set a static page as the front page in the Administration > Settings > Reading panel after logging in as the administrator.

The Wordpress manual entry on this subject can be found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page).

Comment: My comment from Oct 20 2008 (which I put in an answer): Thanks Ruben, but I have already done what you suggest and it's part of the question, not the answer. The question is how to get WP to handle that new home page correctly.